# Loop a json object in a SQL Server 2016 stored procudure

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I have a JSON api

https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&id=17784783,19505939,217873815946,30166592,30310060,30575739,30837262

I want to send data to a stored procured and because of time I had hired two database programmers.

My question: is the only way to parse a JSON object in SQL Server 2016 is with a cursor? In the past I was parsing the JSON object in a .NET WEB API.

Using

```
For Each elements As JToken In result
```

now it's

```
INSERT INTO #temp_values (value)
    SELECT value 
    FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.result')
    WHERE [key] <> 'uids'

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @values NVARCHAR(MAX);

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR

    SELECT value FROM #temp_values

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @values
```

Comment: Can you be slightly more specific how you want to parse it and what you want to do with the data?

Comment: If at all possible, I would advise to parse the JSON before it reaches the database. The .Net framework have some great tools to handle JSON data, while SQL Server's built in tools for JSON are much more limited.